# CSS transition inline menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, css-transitions

I need to do inline menu with transition.

I tried to recode some example into my requirement, but I have a problem with a:hover class - maybe some problem in js class.

But I have no idea how to get a red background under the main link (dropdbtn class) while I scrolling to submenu.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  console.log("ready!");
  $(".dropdown-content").mouseenter(function() {
    $(this).prev().addClass('href-hovered');
  })

  $(".dropdown-content").mouseleave(function() {
    $(this).prev().removeClass('href-hovered');
  })
});
```

```css
.nav {
  width: 1200px !important;
  height: 50px;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.nav ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  display: table;
}
.nav a.dropbtn {
  display: block;
  line-height: 1.5em;
  color: #BCF1F3;
  font-family: 'webfont';
  font-size: 1.5em;
  width: 170px;
}
.nav a.dropbtn:hover {
  display: block;
  //padding:20px 40px;
  line-height: 1.5em;
  color: #BCF1F3;
  font-family: 'webfont';
  font-size: 1.5em;
  width: 170px;
  background: red;
}
.nav ul:before,
.nav ul:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
}
.nav ul:after {
  clear: both;
}
.dropdown {
  float: left;
  background: white;
  position: relative;
  width: 170px;
  min-height: 50px;
}
.dropdown > a {
  color: black;
  display: block;
  padding: 12px 24px;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.dropdown > a:hover {
  color: black;
  background: red;
  display: block;
  padding: 12px 24px;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.dropdown .dropdown-content {
  position: absolute;
  transform: translate3d(0, -100%, 0);
  transition: transform .2s ease-in;
  z-index: -1;
  left: 0;
}
.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  transition-duration: .4s;
  transition-timing-function: ease-out;
  z-index: 1;
}
.dropdown-content {
  background: red;
  list-style: none;
  width: 170px;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
.dropdown-content a {
  display: block;
  padding: 12px 24px;
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  z-index: 100 !important;
}
.nav .red {
  color: #ff6600;
  font-family: 'webfont';
  font: 1.8em;
}
.nav .green {
  color: #00cccc;
  font-family: 'webfont';
}
.nav a:hover .red {
  color: white;
  padding-top: 20px;
  font-family: 'webfont';
}
.nav a:hover .green {
  color: white;
  font-family: 'webfont';
}
.nav a.dropbtn.href-hovered .green {
  color: white;
  font-family: 'webfont';
  background: red;
  width: 170px;
  height: 50px;
}
.nav a.dropbtn.href-hovered .red {
  color: white;
  padding-top: 20px;
  z-index: 2;
  font-family: 'webfont';
  background: red;
  width: 170px;
  height: 50px;
}
.nav a:hover .red,
a:hover .green {
  color: white;
  font-family: 'webfont';
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav class="nav">

  <ul>
    <li class='dropdown'><a class="dropbtn" href="#"><span class="red">nav</span><br><span class="green">1</span></a> 
      <ul class="dropdown-content">
        <li><a href="http://localhost/?page_id=19">Sub_nav</a> 
        </li>
        <li><a href="http://localhost/?page_id=304">Sub_nav</a> 
        </li>
        <li><a href="http://localhost/?page_id=340">Sub_nav</a> 
        </li>
        <li><a href="http://localhost/?page_id=306">Sub_nav</a> 
        </li>
        <li><a href="http://localhost/?page_id=60">Sub_nav</a> 
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>

  </ul>
  <nav>
```

Comment: I'm really not sure what the problem is or what you want to accomplish, all that I can see that this menu is in chaos. Could you please reform your question a bit?

Answer (score 0):

As Mihailo said, your menu is kind of chaotic and overly complex. But to achieve your requirement, just change the style definition

```
nav a.dropbtn:hover
```

to

```
nav:hover a.dropbtn
```

to have the rule applied when the nav block itself is hovered.

Answer (score 0):

Just added `background-color: red;` to `.nav a.dropbtn`. If im correct in understanding [this](https://jsfiddle.net/7Lz1b1o6/) is what you want right?